# why the result is nan in this c float conversion?

Tags: c, types

float and int types are all 4 bytes and I try converting in this way:

```
unsigned int x = 0; // 00000000
x = ~x>>1; // 7fffffff
float f = *((float *)&x);
printf("%f\n", f);
```

Because the first bit in c float number represents `+/-` and the next 8 bits is `exp` in `2^(exp-127)` and the rest will be converted to `0.xxxxx...`, it means I can get max float number:`0|11111111|111...111` but finally I get a `nan`.

So is there anything wrong?

Comment: You are making assumptions on the representation of floats on your platform. Anyway why are you doing this - you are going to have lots of problems in future writing this sort of code

Comment: @EdHeal I think he wants to study about floating-point format.

Comment: @ikh - That will depend on the platform

Comment: @ikh yes~so this confused me

Comment: 2 points 1. how floating point values is different to how integer values are stores so having a float pointer to int is not good. 2. You are having a wrong format specifier to print the float value which will lead to UB

Comment: @Gopi sorry for my carelessness. Format fixed.

Comment: @HayesPan, since you are learning about floating point representation I'd also recommend reading some material about potential problems when using floats. I generally like to recommend "The pitfalls of verifying foating-point computations" by David Monniaux, since it gives you both a theoretical overview of IEEE-754 floats and real-word problems you will encounter.

https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/file/index/docid/281429/filename/floating-point-article.pdf

Comment: @easuter Cool~Thanks a lot^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close, but your exponent is out of range so you have a `NaN`. `FLT_MAX` is:

```
0 11111110 11111111111111111111111
s eeeeeeee mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
```

Note that the max exponent is `11111110`, as `11111111` is reserved for `NaN`s.

The corresponding hex value is:

```
0x7f7fffff
```

So your code should be:

```
unsigned int x = 0x7f7fffff;
float f = *((float *)&x);
printf("%f\n", f);
```

and the result will be:

```
3.4028235E38
```

If you're interested in IEEE-754 format then check out this handy online calculator which converts between binary, hex and float formats: http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

Comment: Because `11111111` is reserved for `NaN`s.

Answer (score 2):

A bit-wise IEEE floating-point standard single precision (32-bit) NaN(Not a Number) would be:

`s111 1111 1xxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx`

where s is the sign (most often ignored in applications) and x is non-zero (the value zero encodes infinities).

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the binary representation of the max `float` value, execute the "inverse":

```
float f = FLT_MAX;
int x = *((int*)&f);
printf("0x%.8X\n",x);
```

The result is `0x7F7FFFFF` (and not `0x7FFFFFFF` as you have assumed).

The C-language standard does not dictate `sizeof(float) == sizeof(int)`.

So you will have to verify this on your platform in order to ensure correct execution.